# React Native Http request dont work in Android

Tags: react-native

Working with requests to the server using **Fetch** and also using **Axios**, when running it on Android emulator/devise it shows me the following error:

[image]

this is the request code:

```
fetch(URL,{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
                email: userEmail,
                password: userPassword
            }),

        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson)=>{
             Alert.alert("bien");
       console.warn(responseJson);
             })
         .catch((error)=>{
         console.error(error);
     console.warn(error);
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem was with the SSL certificate of the URL

Comment: Can you please expand?

Answer (score 16):

Since Http request doesn't work in the latest android updates I think after 28 arrived. So you have to add the following attributes to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest 
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
           android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> 

                // ----------------

        </application>
   </manifest>
```

Comment: thanks this worked and HTTP requests are working now, but HTTPS requests are not working anymore, do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **info.plist** (ProjectFolder->ios->ProjectFolder->info.plist)and add the following before `</plist>`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Now restart project once again .

Comment: Well in iOS it Works but the problem is in android, i already add all the permisions

Answer (score 1):

For those trying out in the iOS, here is the updated version of the answer given by @iamsr

the `info.plist` looks like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

and you can add another key below inside the current `NSAppTransportSecurity`

so the final result to be:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```