# How to fetch data from dot net core in React Native?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net, react-native

[Postman Screenshot of dot net core API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxvUK.png)

Postman fetches the data from my dot net core API but I cannot get the data in React native using the same API. I tried everything like changing port number etc.

React Native API Request

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData= async () => {
     try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:54669/DoctorMaster/Getalldoctorssearch/1062');
        setAppointments(response.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(response.data);
       
        
       
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);     
       
     }
    }
    getData()
  }, [setAppointments, setIsLoading]);
```

Comment: Please, share the code of your attempts to retreive data in react native app. What means can't get the data? Any errors?

Comment: i shared my code in question.and the error is bad request 400

Comment: Are you running your app in docker? Why you send request to localhost in postman?

Comment: No, I'm not running in docker. I'm just running core API in local that is why I call it in localhost and it works well in postman but not in react native

Comment: Ok, I took the point. When I'm doing that in react native, I'm using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) proxy to make my server api public. Ngrok runs proxy and gives you public endpoint which leads to your localhost on selected port. Then set up public endpoint in your react native app to access api.

Comment: do I need to install ngrok as an extension? because ngrok extension is not available in vs 2022 enterprise

Comment: No. You can download ngrok and run it in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below structure

```
fetch(
  "url"
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(token),
    },
  }
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    // Handle response here
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that React Native refuses HTTP requests instead of HTTPS requests by default:

To handle HTTP requests in **Android** see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935563/react-native-http-request-dont-work-in-android)

To handle HTTP requests in **iOS** see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666142/how-to-make-http-requests-in-react-native-ios-application)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch data from localhost which your mobile device won´t be able to fetch the url. You need to publish your API on a Web Server, and then you will be able to fetch the data

Answer (score 0):

Solution: All of the answers did not work for me, I used a visual studio extension called Conveyor by keyoti to solve the issue, this extension allow me to use the API outside of localhost, it will show you the remote URL, use that url to call API from your mobile application

Comment: You might want to edit this to make it sound less like spam.

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to say?

Comment: I wasn't trying to say anything other than what I said.